# Cross-Region Interface endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, endpoint, aws-ssm

all

I have the following questions to ask.

I have two private VPCs - VPC-A (eu-central-1 / 10.10.0.0/24) and VPC-B (eu-west-2 / 172.16.0.0/24)
I have setup Peering connection between them and all traffic is allowed with no restrictions.
VPC-B has ec2messages, ssm and ssmmessages Interface endpoints set in in and a custom DNS server (172.16.0.200) pointing to the IPs of those endpoints.
VPC-A and VPC-B are set two use the Custom DNS as a DNS server via DHCP Opt Set.

Is it possible to connect to private instances in VPC-A via Session Manager and using the Interface endpoints in VPC-B without creaeting additional Interface endpoints in VPC-A ?
Technically I think it should be possible but everything I tried including editing the /etc/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.json.template with the endpoints of VPC-B has failed.

Comment: Try using private IP of the interface endpoint, instead of relying on using its DNS.

Comment: You mean using the private IPs directly in /etc/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.json instead of the DNS names ?